# Dem_NvmBlockID Configuuration

Tags: nvm, diagnostics, autosar

I am facing issue with Dem Module event related data when i make reset data is not written or read from Nvm i have tried NvMReadAll NvMWriteAll commands but by this i am not able to read or write Event related data like DTC Status mask Extd Data Values
Kindly let me know correct process of storing Dem event related data in Nvm from configuration if any point that need to be checked kindly let me know otherwise please let me know sequence of API so that every time dem events related data automatically updated from ram variable to nvm and from nvm to ram variable

Comment: Since you have not even specified, which vendor you use, it is hard to say. If the vendor uses e.g. NVM_DATASET instead of single blocks, this can not be done by `NvM_ReadAll() /NvM_WriteAll()` at all. Second, maybe some configuration items are not properly configured regarding when and what to store. Third, the MemStack has to be initialized and the their MainFunctions called cyclically. .. So best is to consult your vendors documentation for Dem and MemStack integration.

Comment: i am using Electrobit (EB Tresos) and In EB it is mentioned that for DTC Status DEFAULT Block is considered and for Freeze Frame and Extd Data PRIMARY BLOCK but the problem is data with these block is not persistent only on RAM Variable it is updating not in NvM

Comment: In CL30 devices, the NvM Storage is usually handled in the Shutdown phase (by NvM_WriteAll()), and restored on Startup (DemPreInit --> DemInit). In CL15 devices, there is usually no Shutdown phase, therefore, the storage has to usually be triggered all the time. AFAIK, there was an Dem_ImmediateNvStorage option or such. And I also remember, they store the DemEventStatus (UdsExtendedStatusByte) of all DemEvents into a single NvM Block (DEM_DEFAULT). The other data are separated as you said. There are options per Event (e.g. store on TF bit or CDTC bit).

Comment: @kesselhaus Who has this with the datasets?
Would be great if you could document differences in a Q&A or community wiki article here on stack overflow.

Comment: @TorstenKnodt, Neither Vector nor EB use Datasets (DS), don't know for e.g. ETAS. IMHO, since all blocks are handled usually with same size, a DS would be much easier to configure and handle, DS is a single NvmBlock, backed by an array of FEE/EA Blocks. The disadvantage of DS (cannot be used with NvM_Read/WriteAll(), due to NvM_SetDataIndex() call before read/write) does not really apply. Dem is supposed to handle its blocks itself anyway (read each block and update e.g. ThisOpCycle flags). I suggested the DS on an own Dem impl. Create 1 DS with N entries, not N blocks with separate settings

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured primary memory block inside Dem configuration to store the DTC and it's related information ?
If not try to configure block till fee/fls.

Answer (score 0):

First, check in DEM general options parameter *DemEventMemoryEntryStorageTrigger* and verify if ExtendedData, Snapshot, and StatusByte are put in the RAM buffer block. If this works correctly during runtime, but after reset data does not exist in that RAM block it means there is a problem with ReadAll and WriteAll.
For that check configuration in NvM for blocks used by DEM, whether they have enabled options *NvMSelectBlockForReadAll* and *NvMSelectBlockForWriteAll*.